# How to define relationship many-to-many with custom column name and table name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, polymorphism

I have this problem about "How to make a polymorphic relationship out of this?". So, here I have 4 tables. The use case is that table `cashflows` is used for collecting data of incomes and outcomes of `venues` and `departments`, and since there is two types of income and outcomes (venues and department), I create pivot table, and named it `cashflow_transactions` which then I store the income-outcome type there. My question is how can I get, automatically, which cash flow that are from department and or which cash flow are from venues? Presumably, using Polymorphic Many-to-Many Laravel.

```
departments
 - id
 - name
```

---

```
venues
 - id
 - name
```

---

```
cashflows
- id
- payment_type_id
- status
- amount
- description
- reported_at
```

---

```
cashflow_transactions
 - id
 - cashflow_id
 - reference_id
 - type
```

I have tried this function in table `transaction_cashflow`, but it just returns `null`

```
public function departments() {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Department::class, 'cashflowable', 'transaction_cashflows', 'reference_id','id', 'id','reference_id');
}

public function venues() {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Venue::class, 'cashflowable', 'transaction_cashflows', 'reference_id','id', 'id','reference_id');
}
```

Comment: morphedByMany is the inverse of the relationship. Please write the current relationships of the models.

Comment: Nevermind, I used many to many with conditional clause in my Cashflow model

Comment: may be helpful https://github.com/staudenmeir